# Best technique for drawing isometric tiles

Tags: html5, tiles, isometric

I'm thinking about making a simple isometric game with HTML5 Canvas, and wondering what's the fastest way to render the tiles.

Since the tiles are diamond shaped, but drawImage draws rectangles, I have to leave out the corners (the black parts in the following):

[image: sample diamond tile]

I think that leaves me with three options:

1. Use Image objects with alpha channels (.png). I'm afraid this might kill performance.
2. Use a clipping path.  If the renderer is optimized this could be pretty fast.
3. Prerender square tiles, like this:

[image: prerendered square tiles]

I'd have the black square as one actual tile in memory, and I'd draw such a tile for the green field, and all fields next to it, or above and below. The diagonal (blue) fields would be make up of the corners of the rectangular tiles. This would avoid clipping or alpha channels, but I would have to prerender all possible combinations of tiles, and it seems like overkill.

What's the best or fastest way to do isometric tiles? What do other games, like FarmVille, use?

Comment: I had the same "issue", decided to test my luck with the Isometric Game Engine, but failed because it took me too long to connect with jQuery, something I depended on for ajax/php hooking. So currently I'm building the engine myself as a jQ plugin. Faved and +1 this ost. Good luck.

Comment: I think "best technique" is kind of loaded, and will depend on the requirements of the game, and technology being used and the developer creating the game.

Comment: What problem are you actually having?  It seems like you've provided three answers to your own question inside the question text?

Comment: All of the answers are actually just opinions of how to do this. Since the question is asking for exactly that. Not constructive for the site.

Comment: This doesn't have enough votes: [BEST BEST BESSSSSSST! argh?](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/636/best-best-bessssssst-argh)

Comment: Guess you should follow the advice found here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/638/7191

Comment: @Byte56 & others: I'm looking for the fastest way to draw tiles onto a canvas, that is, the way that gives me the most FPS. The reason I'm saying 'best' is that I'm looking for the fastest *reasonable* method (wrt. development time and ease, memory usage, ...), not just the fastest method *period*. I don't have any HTML5 canvas experience and am looking for advice from people who do.

Comment: @Luceos: Thanks, I was also thinking of using an engine, and maybe I will in the end. But since it's been a while since I've done a game, and I don't know much about canvas, I thought it would be interesting to get my hands dirty and do the low level stuff myself. Good luck to you, too.

Comment: @TrevorPowell: I don't have a concrete problem, I would like to know which approach gives me the highest FPS before I start implementing. (I think you could say my problem is that many simple 2D web games run jerky on moderate hardware (e.g. Tablets, eeePC), although 15 years ago graphically similar DOS and Win95 games ran more fluid on much simpler hardware. I think that's silly and would like to get my game as smooth as possible.)

Comment: So you don't know that this is actually a performance problem?  You're just trying to optimise the code before it's written?  In that case, -1 and voting to close.

Answer (score 11):

Using transparency (alpha channel) is the way to go, I recommend.

This means that when you want a vertical object on the tile like this:

[image: tile with tree]

Then you can do it easily if your renderer draws the tiles back-to-front i.e. painters algorithm.

IMAGE CREDIT: Reiner's tileset.

Answer (score 9):

While the method described by sws and MarkR is also what I prefer, I would like to present an alternative approach.

A hackish option for creating an isometric look with minimal effort is to actually use orthogonal tiles, and use context.transform to set a projection matrix which makes the map look isometric (or a combination of context.rotate and context.scale when you don't know how projection matrices work).

See [the specification for canvas transformation methods](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations) for details.

Tile image:

[image: base tile image]

Drawing code:

```
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, x * img.width, y * img.height);
        }
    }
```

Result before matrix application:

[image: without transformation matrix applied]

Same code with same tile image after applying this transformation matrix:

```
    ctx.transform(  1,   0.5,
                   -1,   0.5,
                  160,   0    );
```

[image: with transformation matrix]

With the dashed grid removed from the tile image and changed the tile offset in the drawing code to `img.width - 1` and `img.height - 1` to get rid of the gaps caused by the transformation. Suddenly the tile looks half as ugly:

[image: with matrix and some tweaks]

The main drawback of this method is that when you design your tiles in a graphic editor, they won't really be what-you-see-is-what-you-get. You will also encounter problems when you want to draw any objects which are not on the floor but standing upright. For these you can switch off the transformation matrix before drawing them, but then you will have to calculate the position yourself. You can use these formulas for that:

```
var xScreen = xWorld * 1   + yWorld * -1  + 160;
var yScreen = xWorld * 0.5 + yWorld * 0.5 + 0;
```

(note how the numbers from the transformation matrix reappear in these formulas - you are doing the matrix multiplication yourself here).

**So why should I do this?**

This method is good when you:

1. aren't experienced with designing isometric tiles, but you have orthogonal ones
2. don't want to spend much time on developing an isometric graphic engine, which is somewhat more difficult than an orthogonal one.

Another interesting feature is that when you know your way around matrix calculation, you can modify the projection matrix between frames to zoom, tilt and rotate the map in real-time for some nice fake-3d effects (try to do THAT with isometric tiles).

But when you know how to handle isometric tiles, both artistically and technically, and you don't need any fake-perspective trickery I would rather suggest you to go with diamond-shaped tiles with transparency.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do this. This way you can have "flat" or "top-down" tiles. However, it means that any "3d" elements in the tiles can't be done easily. I prefer to do this transformation ahead of time.

Comment: +1 if not only for the expert explanation! Well done.

Comment: @MarkR: I expanded my answer a lot after you made your comment, you might want to take a look if it still applies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up! That's a very interesting technique, I didn't think about doing that before. However, as I'm starting from scratch (and am equally bad at drawing isometric and square tiles ;-)), I'll go for true isometric tiles. Also, this seems to be not very fast. I did a small benchmark, and blitting tiles without a transformation matrix to integer pixel positions is about 3x faster than with the transformation on my PC. Still I might use this for some special effects.

Comment: Any way to add some z level to this map?

Answer (score 3):

1. You're using context.drawImage to copy pixel data from one source (Image, or offscreen canvas) to another (offscreen or onscreen canvas), which handles alpha gracefully out-of-the-box. Canvas is hardware-accelerated, so testing will allow you to determine whether there's a discernible difference in rendering speeds w.r.t. alpha- vs opaque-pixels.
2. Clipping will require you to push/pop the context's state when defining a clipping path once per tile, which could be a costly operation considering isometric's overdraw.
3. Prerendered tiles would, as you state, require an immense number of 'connector' tiles to be drawn, which may or may not be feasable. (I'm leaning more toward "may not".)

A fourth solution would be to adopt a pre-rendered "chunk" (PRC) of tiles, generated once to offscreen canvases, and then cover the screen with the PRCs once per frame. There would still be overdraw, but building the PRC once and rendering it with an offset determined by the player character's (or view camera's) position relative to the PRC should be a relatively simple operation. This would allow you to combine rendering with option #1, which is IMO the best option if performance weren't a consideration (since it's simplest to implement).

Answer (score 3):

A little alpha channel doesn't hurt much, but if you want to avoid it consider using two quarter tiles, this also gives you some room for making nice tile transitions without doing a plethora of different images, that is probably the biggest advantage:

[image: Rectangular sub-tile pattern]